# $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2+x^3}{x^2\cdot \left | x-1 \right | \cdot \frac{3}{4} \left |x-4 \right |^{\frac{4}{3}}} dx$ convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Does $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2+x^3}{x^2\cdot \left | x-1 \right | \cdot \frac{3}{4} \left |x-4  \right |^{\frac{4}{3}}} dx$$ converge?

Domain of this integrand is $x \in \mathbb{R} : x\neq 0, x\neq1, x\neq4$. So sought-for integral is determined by the formula 
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{d_1}f + \int_{d_1}^{1}f + \int_{1}^{d_2}f+\int_{d_2}^{4}f + \int_{4}^{d_3}f+ \int_{d_3}^{+\infty}f$$
$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ converges if all integrals in rhs of the formula is converges and diverges if at least diverges. 
But the problem is that integral like $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x^2+x^3}{x^2\cdot (1-x) \cdot \frac{3}{4} (4-x)^{\frac{4}{3}}} dx$$ is very difficult to compute. And to be honest I'm not sure that my thoughts are correct.

Comment: Near $1$ the integrand is greater than a positive constant times $1/|x-1|.$ So what do you think?

Comment: You can factor $x^2$ in the numerator and cancel it with the $x^2$ in the denominator to make a simpler expression to integrate.

Comment: @zhw. does it means that integrand can be approximated by function $C \cdot \frac{1}{\left | x-1 \right |}$?

Comment: We don't need to approximate, "greater than" is the point.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what it gives.

Comment: What is $\int_0^2 (1/|x-1|)\,dx?$